# Redux replacing temporary ID with the server ID

Tags: javascript, redux, ngrx

I'm working with Redux application and normalized state. I have the following state:

```
{
    posts: {
        byId: {
            "post1" : {
                id : "post1",
                author : "user1",
                body : "......",
                comments : ["comment1", "comment2"]    
            },
        },
        allIds : ["post1"]
    },
```

When the user adds a new post, I am generating a temporary id in the client and add it to the store. When I'm saving the new post in the server, I'm getting back the new ID that the server generated and replace the temporary id with the new one.

But what if someone is already listening to the old id? It will not exist anymore. What is the way for doing such a thing?

Comment: Why do you make it yourself so hard?

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: Why do you work with 2 different ID's?

Comment: Because I need to add it to the store before saving it in the server.